# How to use the first-of-type pseudo class along with the first-letter pseudo element in my style rule selector

Tags: css

How do I correctly format this style rule?

So far, I have:

```
#speech p:first-letter {
    font-size: 4em;
    float: left;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 0.3em;
    padding-right: 0.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    border: solid black;
    border-right-width: 0.02em;
    border-bottom-width: 0.02em;
}
```

This changes the first letter of ALL my paragraphs in the #speech section.
How do I include the first-of-type pseudo class to make sure only the first paragraph's letter is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#speech p:first-of-type:first-letter {
    font-size: 4em;
    float: left;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 0.3em;
    padding-right: 0.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    border: solid black;
    border-right-width: 0.02em;
    border-bottom-width: 0.02em;
}
```

please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/jKzds).

Answer (score 1):

just use both 
first-child pseudo class and first letter pseudo class

see fiddlel - http://jsfiddle.net/QX45P/

```
p:first-child:first-letter {
    font-size: 4em;
    float: left;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 0.3em;
    padding-right: 0.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    border: solid black;
    border-right-width: 0.02em;
    border-bottom-width: 0.02em;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use first child here, as it will select any element which is 1st child of `#speech`, you should prefer using `:first-of-type` instead

Comment: true ...  note that `:first-of-type` is not supported in IE8 whereas `:first-child` is (with the right DOCTYPE) if that event matters to you..

Comment: I used first-of-type:first-letter